# How to bypass authority log in for IP CAM using TECHview Jaycar model 720p?

Tags: vlc, ip-camera

I have port forwarded it successfully and it opens in my browser to see on the web but no-one else can see it because it is password locked even though I have tried removing passwords and allowing in camera settings connect by anyone.

Also I had to grab the url in the guts of code just to get it to work for me without prompting for pass so I assumed it would be the same for others but this is not the case. The code I am using is quicktime embed code :-

```
<embed src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/iphone/11?admin:&" autoplay="true" 
controller="true" scale="tofit" showstatusbar="false" 
type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/index.html" 
height=“240" width="320”>
```

Comment: I worked out what to do but really plug ins are a thing of the past so there are still so many users denied access because of quicktime incompatibility like CHROME browsers and ANDROID platform. You need to secure camera with admin user password then create guest user and password and then when you look will end up with an address including guest user and pass and then it will work.

Comment: If you were serious you'd install a media server and stream it and then give users options between plugins and versions of media embed. VLC is my fav player - it opens practically ANYTHING. If I could learn how to stream on terminal and then offer html5 as well as transitional more currently compliant html I'd do that.